# Do I have to use in app purchases for my app or I can use a third party payment gateway?

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, payment

I have a question related to an application I am currently developing.
I don't know if should use in app purchases or not.
The idea is that currently you can transfer money from a user to another just like Revolut does. For this you pay let's say $1 per transfer.
Beside this, the application makes queries every 6 months to get some info from a financial institution and each query is paid by me as the API is payment per request.

Now, if I want to have some plans in the application like free and premium and for premium let's say you can do free transfers between users (just like Revolut) and have a monthly query to the financial institution, do I need to use Apple's IAP and pay a 30% tax for each subscription or can I use a 3rd party payment gateway?
I really couldn't find any response on this on the guidelines and I am trying to figure out how Revolut for example can use their payment method in order to purchase plans ?!

Thanks!

Comment: If you are developing a finance/baking app, then would suggest don't use Apple IAP. IAP is suitable for purchasing any content/game/Magazine not for transferring money.

Comment: You would not use IAP for the $1 fee. You would have to use IAP for the premium subscription.  Apple's commission is 15% if you earn less than $1M per year.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS, yes, but am I allowed not to use Apple IAP when purchasing the plan itself?

Comment: @Paulw11 but how come are you allowed on Revolut to buy premium subscriptions without using IAP?

Comment: you can use but in banking apps avoid IAP. Might be in the future Apple reject your app if you are dealing in Billion $. Better to handle all these at the banking server wrt user profile. I'm sure you have good database management. Also in future, Im sure you are going to add device management with your app. You would not allow more than 2/3 devices per user profile now in this situation IAP would be a big issue for your customer if they are trying to access from his friend's phone.

Comment: I imagine you can only subscribe to the premium service on their web site, not in app.

Comment: @Paulw11 you can subscribe in the app. I tried it. the only difference is that it takes money from your revolut account. you can't use any other method to pay for their plans.

Comment: Then submit your app and see what happens. That is the only way you can find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add apple's IAP only. You can just use payment gateways for taking direct payments from the client. For adding subscriptions you need to use IAP only.